# Button with dual function: Open a link in a _blank window, plus a different link in _self

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events

Is this possible at all? I'm building a simple Facebook app and want a button to load an external link in a `_blank` window, while the next page of the app loads in the `_self` window. I'm very much a novice at JavaScript, so any help/advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Java and Javascript are not same.

Answer (score 1):

Add a click event listener to your button that executes the following lines:

```
window.open('http://www.example.org/external_link.html', 'New Window');
window.location.href = 'http://www.example.org/internal_link.html';
```

The first line might get blocked by some popup blockers but let's give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a million for your reply. It worked just as you suggested. The external_link opens in a new tab in most browsers, and a new window in some. 
I tried to add parameters for the size of the window: 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=350,height=250'
But it only goes to default size. 
Howandever, I presume there's not much point in spending too much time on this, as like you say, popup blockers will make it obsolete anyway... and I'm presuming popup blockers are pretty much a default for most web users these days.
Thanks again for your help :)